# How do I identify what is not a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm referring the book "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Prof. Gilbert Strang.
There is a problem question which goes as follows:

> Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ are actually subspaces?
>
> (a) The plane of vectors $(b_1,~ b_2,~ b_3)$ with $b_1 = b_2$.
>
> (b) The plane of vectors with $b_1 = 1$.
>
> (c) The vectors with $b_1b_2b_3 = 0$.
>
> (d) All linear combinations of $v = (1, 4, 0)$ and $w = (2, 2, 2)$.
>
> (e)All vectors that satisfy $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0$.
>
> (f) All vectors with $b_1 \le b_2 \le b_3$.

As per the given solution; option - (a), (d), (e) are sub-spaces which I can understand how.

Also, what I understood about Options (c), (f) not being a subspace :
Option (c), since $b_1b_2b_3 = 0$ indicate one vector to be a zero vector, but just those $3$ vectors would not be enough to span a space/subspace.

Option (f), again, $3$ vectors cannot be a subspace alone.

However, I'm facing difficulty in understanding why is option b, not subspaces?

Option (b), $b_1 = 1$, then $cb_1$ is a line passing through origin which is a subspace.

Then why is it not included as a subspace in the solution?

Comment: A subspace must contain the zero vector.

Comment: Drawing the sets can help. Subspaces of Euclidean space are the trivial subspaces, lines, planes, and hyperplanes passing through the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set (b) is not a subspace because $(0,0,0)$ does not belong to it.

The set (c) is not a subspace because, for instance, $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ belong to it, but not their sum.

And the set (f) is not a subspace because, for instance $(0,1,2)$ belongs to it, but $-(0,1,2)$ doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! Got it.